# Laravel load relationship with 1 column values as array

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

There is a way in Laravel to load a relationship with only 1 column value and to have it as an array?

I have a `belongsToMany` relationship from `Page` Model to `Country`, `State` models.

```php
public function countries(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Country::class, 'page_country', 'page_id', 'country_id');
}

public function states(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(State::class, 'page_state', 'page_id', 'state_id');
}
```

When I load these relationships I need to get the result as an array of values `[1,2,3,4]` (ids of the related model). In other words, I need to load only `id` of `states` and `countries` for my `Page`

So instead of key-value pair:

```php
[
   'states' => ['id' => 1, 'id' => 2, ...],
   'countries' => ['id' => 1, 'id' => 2, ...]
]
```

I want to achieve this:

```php
[
   'states' => [1, 2, ...],
   'countries' => [1, 2, ...]
]
```

What I'm doing currently is:

Load the relationship:

```php
public function view(Page $page){
    
    $page->load([
        'countries:id',
        'states:id'
    ]);

    //Transform to get array of ids for each relation
    $page->countries->transform(function($item){
        return $item->id;
    });

    $page->states->transform(function($item){
        return $item->id;
    });

    //and return as json
    return response()->json($page)
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to achieve this? Because when I need to load 10 relationships, I need to run 10 transforms functions.

Comment: There is also `$page->countries->pluck('id')->toArray()` or `$page->countries->modelKeys()` for collections https://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-get-array-of-ids-from-collection-pluck-or-modelkeys/

Comment: Hi @SuperDJ, I will still need to write this 10 times, if I load 10 relationships. Plus is not modifying the relationship, but instead, returns a new value, so I will have to marge it back with the parent.

Comment: You're going to need to clarify what your problem is; there's a reason nobody's answered the question yet. Sticking a bounty on without improving the question isn't going to help you get a good answer.

Comment: Hi @miken32 what exactly is not clear?

Comment: "I want to get a results as [1,2,3,4]" what does this mean? What result do you currently get?

Comment: @miken32 updated.

Comment: Hi, @miken32 added more descriptions, thank you for assisting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible with eager loading relationships, to the best of my knowledge. Since eager loading already does an extra database query for each relationship, there's no additional load on the database to do this:

```php
public function view(Page $page)
{    
    $result = $page->toArray();
    $result['countries'] = $page->countries()->pluck('id');
    $result['states'] = $page->states()->pluck('id');

    //and return as json
    return response()->json($result)
}
```

You seem rather concerned about having to do this 10 times, so you could put it in a loop if you like.

```php
public function view(Page $page)
{    
    $result = $page->toArray();
    $relationships = ['countries', 'states', ];
    foreach ($relationship as $rel) {
        $result[$rel] = $page->{$rel}()->pluck('id');
    }

    //and return as json
    return response()->json($result)
}
```

But really, you only write the code once so what's the problem with doing it 10 times?

---

You may also want to look at Eloquent [resources and collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources); depending on your use case they might be helpful.

---

One last suggestion is to get away from Eloquent and use query builder:

```php
public function view(int $page)
{
    $result = Page::select('pages.*')
        ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(countries.id) AS countries')
        ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(states.id) AS states')
        ->leftJoin('countries', 'countries.page_id', 'pages.id')
        ->leftJoin('states', 'states.page_id', 'pages.id')
        ->where('pages.id', $page)
        ->groupBy('pages.id')
        ->get();

    //and return as json
    return response()->json($result)
}
```

This has the advantage of greatly reducing the number of hits to your database at the expense of having to be familiar with some ugly SQL syntax. It will return the foreign IDs as a comma separated list, which you can deal with on the client side, or before returning the response.

Comment: Thank you Miken32, I guess "ugly" SQL is the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) for this. Add these functions to your `Page.php` model:

```php
public function getCountryIdsAttribute() {
  return $this->countries->pluck('id');
}

public function getStateIdsAttribute() {
  return $this->states->pluck('id');
}
```

Additionally, if you want to automatically include these in a JSON response, add the following as well:

```php
protected $appends = ['countryIds', 'stateIds'];
```

Now, your code would be mostly the same:

```php
public function view(Page $page) {    
  $page->load([
    'countries:id',
    'states:id'
  ]);

  return response()->json($page);
}
```

You would still want to eager load `countries` and `states` for `$this->countries->pluck('id')` and `$this->states->pluck('id')` to function without calling 2 additional queries, but your Response would then look like this:

```js
[
   'states' => ['id' => 1, 'id' => 2, ...],
   'countries' => ['id' => 1, 'id' => 2, ...],
   'country_ids' => [1, 2, ...],
   'state_ids' => [1, 2, ...]
]
```

If you didn't want to include `states` and `countries`, you'd simply add them to `hidden` in your `Page.php` Model:

```php
protected $hidden = ['countries', 'states'];`
```

Which would result in:

```js
[
   'country_ids' => [1, 2, ...],
   'state_ids' => [1, 2, ...]
]
```

You can see more about `appends` and `hidden` Model properties here:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization

The main drawback to this is that your fields are no longer named `countries` and `states` when returned as a JSON object, but this does remove the need for additional iterations while mapping, manually calling overrides, etc.

Answer (score 0):

//i am in Model where states are listed in array

```
public function countries() 
{
 return Countries::find($this->states);
}
```

// I am in blade

```
@foreach($item->countries() as $countries)
    {{ $countries->name.', '}}
@endforeach
```